# How to correctly navigate to another fragment

Tags: android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

Within an Android app that I wrote, the navigation stops working correctly after the app executes the following two lines of Kotlin code:

```
    val navControl = activity?.findNavController(R.id.fragNavHost)
    navControl.navigate(R.id.actChaptersToRead)
```

I reproduced the same behavior by starting with the standard project "Bottom Navigation Views Activity" that Android Studio creates from the File -> New Project menu item.

To reproduce the behavior, I did the following:

1. Created a new "Bottom Navigation Views Activity".
2. Added a button to the fragment_dashboard.xml layout. This is the 2nd of three layouts that the navigation controller navigates.

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_to_notifications"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="To Notifications"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_dashboard" />
```

3. Made the button navigate to the third fragment (fragment_notifications.xml) by adding this Kotlin code to onCreateView in DashboardFragment.kt

```
    val button: Button = binding.buttonToNotifications
    button.setOnClickListener { view: View ->
        val navController = view.findNavController()
        navController.navigate(R.id.navigation_notifications)
    }
```

After running the app, I pressed the "Dashboard" icon in the bottom navigation view which caused the app to navigate to the fragment_dashboard. (See screenshot below.) Then I pressed the "To Notifications" button that I added in step 2 above which caused the app execute the onClickListener in step 3 above and to navigate to the fragment_notifications. However, at this point, when I press the "Dashboard" icon in the bottom navigation view, the app will not navigate to the fragment_dashboard. Instead, it stays on the fragment_notifications.

[image: A screenshot of the Dashboard fragment that contains a button to navigate to the Notifications fragment]

There are no errors in Logcat. There are two warnings that my be related.

1. OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application. Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.
2. Compiler allocated 4533KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()

What am I doing wrong in the Kotlin code in step 3 that causes the navigation to break after that code is executed?